# Pass multiple images with nested attributes in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to pass multiple images with accepts_nested_attributes_for and polymorphic association. But getting this error  `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.Though I know I have done all the setup still I don't know what am I missing. And I have used `carrier wave` for image uploading.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :images,-> { where(object_type: 'User') },as: :object,:foreign_key => 'object_id'  ,dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images 
     
  validates :first_name,presence: true
end
```

**Image.rb**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :remember_id
  after_destroy :remove_id_directory

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
  belongs_to :object,polymorphic: true

  validates :name,presence: true

  protected

  def remember_id
    @id = id
  end

  def remove_id_directory
    FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/image/image/#{@id}", :force => true)
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.images.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new 
     @user.images.build(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
     
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,images_attributes: [:name,:image,:user_id ])
  end
end
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user,html: {multipart: :true} do |f| %>   
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :images_attributes do |images_fields| %>
    Nama  : <%= images_fields.text_field :name %>
    Image: <%= images_fields.file_field :image,:multiple => true %>

  <% end %>
  <%=f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**Log**

```
   Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-27 11:20:29 +0530
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wpb1cqph+SAucEfeb0isx7DKtsV4PQeyq47xZbz/Ac7cSfoSleBXynNJiT+kNni5OaX/DqNhR+h1Xvli2QyBbg==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"adasd", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003819838 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170127-3305-16cl68l.png>, @original_filename="1.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[images_attributes][0][image][]\"; filename=\"1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000038197e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170127-3305-8o6vn7.png>, @original_filename="27_dec.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[images_attributes][0][image][]\"; filename=\"27_dec.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000038196a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170127-3305-1j7hl1r.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2017-01-13 16:52:49.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[images_attributes][0][image][]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2017-01-13 16:52:49.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Unpermitted parameter: image
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Hi. It'd help us to help you if you had a look in your logs (either in the console window or in `log/development.log` and found the stacktrace that matches that error message and copy/pasted it into your question. That would help us figure out what line (not only in your code, but also in carrierwave) is causing that error.

Comment: But just a quick squiz also tells me that this is probably not quite right: `f.fields_for :images_attributes` it should probably be: `f.fields_for :images` (in the form. in the permit/require else it's correct to use `images_attributes`)

Comment: Okay I am showing you my development.log

Comment: Taryn East- It doesn't work I tried with f.fields_for :images

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: Do this `f.fields_for :images, Image.new`

Comment: ABPrime - Sorry it is not working

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: let me know the error please. and don't forget to add id into attributes `images_attributes: [:id, :name,:image,:user_id ]`

Comment: the problem is I am trying to upload multiple images but only first image is getting uploading and getting saved in database and rest are not saving .I am updating my development.log

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: Do this in create `@user.images.build(user_params)` in place of `@user = User.new user_params`

Comment: Doesn't work the error is coming unknown attribute 'first_name' for Image.

and multiple images are not uploading .And I am updating the log and users controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134144/discussion-between-abprime-and-aniket-shivam-tiwari).

Comment: There is probably more than one thing wrong in the code. You definitely need `.fields_for :images` - if you don't have this it will not work, but it will not be the only thing you need to fix to make it work. This will, however, let you see the next error, and after you fix that, we will see the next error... eventually we will fix all the errors :)

Comment: @TarynEast: Hey please join us in discussion.

Comment: `@user.images.build(user_params)` this is also a bug... you don't want to put `user` params into building an `image`, and yuou don't need it in the `create` method at all if you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` in your use model (which you do). Just remove that line entirely from your `create` action.

Comment: I don't really "do" discussion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)  
    if @user.save
        params[:images_attributes]['image'].each do |a|

          @image_attachment = @user.images.create!(:image => a,:name=>  params[:images_attributes][:name].join)

       end

        redirect_to users_path

    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user,html: {multipart: :true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name %> 

    <%= f.fields_for :images do |images_fields| %>
    Name  : <%= images_fields.text_field :name,name: "images_attributes[name][]" %>
    Image: <%= images_fields.file_field :image,:multiple => true,name: "images_attributes[image][]" %>

    <% end %>
       <%=f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```